# Flow vector field in bucket of water with hole

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, flow

I'm looking to calculate the vector field that governs the flow of water out of an orifice with a view to comparing it to the movement of a crowd out of a building through a single exit point.

What equations should i be looking at?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the door is so wide that it can let out many people at a time then perhaps fluid analogy might be a passable approximation. But if the door is small enough that it can let out only a few people at a time, I think flow analogy would be inappropriate. A simple counting procedure should suffice in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the details that you wish to get out. In the most ideal scenario, you could use a potential flow solution and just focus on one quadrant of a sink solution. This would give you the streamlines and vector field of the solution in a closed form analytical answer. Although, in this case the velocity becomes a singularity at the sink, so perhaps maybe not your best model, but would be a start. If you wished to have a more reduced order model, (i.e. forget the slogging of people along the walls as they try to squeeze through a door), then you could go with the Euler equation. This equation neglects the effects of vicious forces and dissipation and is commonly used to model the ideal motion of fluids. You might be able to obtain a closed form analytical answer, however, you could always seek a numerical route. Finally, as nrabbit mentioned, the full fledged equations of motion for a fluid are the Navier-Stokes equation. This equation will allow you to account for the viscous forces and dissipation within your solution. However, an analytical answer for this equation is few and far between. Only a select few exact answers exist for very reduced problems. If you go a numerical route, I would seek a laminar solution to avoid complications with the closure problem, as I doubt people will be fluctuating around in a room or through a door.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any examples for the numerical resolution of such equations?

Comment: You will have to be more specific on what you mean by numerical resolution.  Do you mean do I have numerical results for this particular problem?

Comment: The solution of any of the mathematical models mentioned above (including the potential flow model, and most certainly including the Euler equations) will be well beyond your grasp. The mathematics of what you are looking for go far beyond simple calculus. I will also note that, since you are really interested in an idealized model for the motion of people, the appropriate continuum mechanical model would be the one of a compressible, non-Newtonian fluid. Long story short, this is hard stuff.

Comment: I see, I mean the numerical resolution via programming as opposed to analytic resolution.  I understand the point about non newtonian fluids, i should however get some semblance of correlation using a simple fluid model, right?

Comment: @user3161003: It depends on your parameters, and what you mean by "some semblance". For example, in the case of the motion of people through exits of a venue, you can easily get complete choking, meaning the flow goes to zero. This cannot happen for a Newtonian fluid. It may turn out that other (non-continuum) types of models are more appropriate for the application(s) you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

For most fluid mechanics problems the governing equations are the Navier-stokes equations. Here specifically you'd want the momentum equations.